# github actions setup.py SOURCES.txt

Tags: python, github-actions, pypi

I'm trying to publish a package to pypi from github using actions. Something not working as expected in github.

MANIFEST.IN:

```
include LICENSE
include requirements.txt
include README.md

include solvency2sf/*.csv
```

setup.py:

```
setuptools.setup(
name="solvency2sf",
version="0.0.20",

packages=setuptools.find_packages(include=['solvency2sf', 'solvency2sf.*']),
python_requires='>=3.6',
include_package_data=True,
install_requires=dependencies,)
```

Now running this:

```
        python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

gives different results on my local machine versus when run via github actions.
The file egg-info/SOURCES.txt either

- includes all of the desired csv files, when run on my local machine, or
- includes none of them, apparently ignoring the Manifest.IN

Any ideas?

Comment: Can I guess your local machine is Windows (case-insensitive filesystem) and Github Actions runs Linux (case-sensitive filesystem)? The problem I see is that the file must not be named `MANIFEST.IN` or `Manifest.IN`, it must be `MANIFEST.in`

Comment: bingo. thank you!